# How to deselect a selected div only when having the mouse down on an unselected div, and not when I have the mouse down on a selected div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been coding this selection system that allows me to select widgets and drag a bunch of them, the problem is that when I select two widgets and I drag the other widget that's not selected, they're all being dragged, I don't want that to happen.

What is supposed to happen is that when I put my mouse down on a non-selected widget, all of the selected widgets have to not be selected anymore (that means the ".selected" class is removed). The problem is that I'm confused on how to apply this only to the non-selected widgets, it has to not apply to selected widgets.

Here is the code before I tried:

```js
let isSelecting = false;
let selectionStartX, selectionStartY, selectionEndX, selectionEndY;
let selectionRectangle;
let draggedElements = [];
const widgets = document.querySelectorAll('.widgets');
const widgetContainer = document.getElementById('widget-container');
document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  const header = event.target.closest('.widget-header');
  if (header) {
    const widget = header.parentElement;
    draggedElements = Array.from(widgets).filter((widget) => widget.classList.contains('selected'));
    draggedElements.forEach((widget) => {
      const shiftX = event.clientX - widget.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      const shiftY = event.clientY - widget.getBoundingClientRect().top;

      function moveElement(event) {
        const x = event.clientX - shiftX;
        const y = event.clientY - shiftY;

        widget.style.left = x + 'px';
        widget.style.top = y + 'px';
      }

      function stopMoving() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveElement);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopMoving);
      }
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveElement);
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopMoving);
    });
    return;
  }
  const isWidgetClicked = Array.from(widgets).some((widget) => {
    const widgetRect = widget.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      event.clientX >= widgetRect.left &&
      event.clientX <= widgetRect.right &&
      event.clientY >= widgetRect.top &&
      event.clientY <= widgetRect.bottom
    );
  });
  if (!isWidgetClicked && event.target !== selectionRectangle) { // Check if the target is not the selection rectangle
    isSelecting = true;
    selectionStartX = event.clientX;
    selectionStartY = event.clientY;
    selectionRectangle = document.createElement('div');
    selectionRectangle.id = 'selection-rectangle';
    selectionRectangle.style.position = 'absolute';
    selectionRectangle.style.border = '2px dashed blue';
    selectionRectangle.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    selectionRectangle.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(selectionRectangle);
    // Remove selected class from widgets
    widgets.forEach((widget) => {
      widget.classList.remove('selected');
    });
  }
});
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (isSelecting) {
    selectionEndX = event.clientX;
    selectionEndY = event.clientY;
    let width = Math.abs(selectionEndX - selectionStartX);
    let height = Math.abs(selectionEndY - selectionStartY);
    selectionRectangle.style.width = width + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.height = height + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.left = Math.min(selectionEndX, selectionStartX) + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.top = Math.min(selectionEndY, selectionStartY) + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.display = 'block';
    widgets.forEach((widget) => {
      const widgetRect = widget.getBoundingClientRect();
      const isIntersecting = isRectangleIntersecting(widgetRect, {
        x: Math.min(selectionStartX, selectionEndX),
        y: Math.min(selectionStartY, selectionEndY),
        width,
        height,
      });
      if (isIntersecting) {
        widget.classList.add('selected');
      } else {
        widget.classList.remove('selected');
      }
    });
  }
});
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  if (isSelecting) {
    isSelecting = false;
    selectionRectangle.remove();
  }
});

function isRectangleIntersecting(rect1, rect2) {
  return (
    rect1.left >= rect2.x &&
    rect1.top >= rect2.y &&
    rect1.right <= rect2.x + rect2.width &&
    rect1.bottom <= rect2.y + rect2.height
  );
}
// Make the DIV element draggable:
dragElement(document.getElementById("widget1"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
// Make the DIV element draggable:
dragElement(document.getElementById("widget2"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}

// Make the DIV element draggable:
dragElement(document.getElementById("widget3"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#selection-rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999999;
}

.widgets.selected {
  outline-color: blue;
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: dashed;
}

.widgets {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid #212128;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 166px;
  min-height: 66px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  image-resolution: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.widget-header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #040c14;
  outline-color: white;
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="widget1" class="widgets" style="left: 50px; top: 50px;">
  <div id="widget1header" class="widget-header"></div>
</div>
<div id="widget2" class="widgets" style="left: 150px; top: 150px;">
  <div id="widget2header" class="widget-header"></div>
</div>
<div id="widget3" class="widgets" style="left: 250px; top: 250px;">
  <div id="widget3header" class="widget-header"></div>
</div>
```

I tried creating a function that checks if a div is selected or not, if not, when the mouse is down on it, it unselects everything else.

**It didn't work for some reason**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your second `<script>` tag, its content is repeated and unnecessary. In the mousedown handler, check if the clicked widget has `selected` class or not and add to `draggedElements` accordingly.

```js
let isSelecting = false;
let selectionStartX, selectionStartY, selectionEndX, selectionEndY;
let selectionRectangle;
let draggedElements = [];
const widgets = document.querySelectorAll('.widgets');
const widgetContainer = document.getElementById('widget-container');

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  const header = event.target.closest('.widget-header');
  if (header) {
    const widget = header.parentElement;
    // If the clicked widget is not selected
    if (!widget.classList.contains('selected')) {
      // deselect all widgets 
      widgets.forEach((widget) => {
        widget.classList.remove('selected');
      });
      // and only drag the clicked one
      draggedElements = [widget];
    } else {
      // otherwise drag the selected 
      draggedElements = Array.from(widgets).filter((widget) => widget.classList.contains('selected'));
    }

    draggedElements.forEach((widget) => {
      const shiftX = event.clientX - widget.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      const shiftY = event.clientY - widget.getBoundingClientRect().top;

      function moveElement(event) {
        const x = event.clientX - shiftX;
        const y = event.clientY - shiftY;

        widget.style.left = x + 'px';
        widget.style.top = y + 'px';
      }

      function stopMoving() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveElement);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopMoving);
      }

      document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveElement);
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopMoving);
    });

    return;
  }

  const isWidgetClicked = Array.from(widgets).some((widget) => {
    const widgetRect = widget.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      event.clientX >= widgetRect.left &&
      event.clientX <= widgetRect.right &&
      event.clientY >= widgetRect.top &&
      event.clientY <= widgetRect.bottom
    );
  });

  if (!isWidgetClicked && event.target !== selectionRectangle) { // Check if the target is not the selection rectangle
    isSelecting = true;
    selectionStartX = event.clientX;
    selectionStartY = event.clientY;
    selectionRectangle = document.createElement('div');
    selectionRectangle.id = 'selection-rectangle';
    selectionRectangle.style.position = 'absolute';
    selectionRectangle.style.border = '2px dashed blue';
    selectionRectangle.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    selectionRectangle.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(selectionRectangle);

    // Remove selected class from widgets
    widgets.forEach((widget) => {
      widget.classList.remove('selected');
    });
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (isSelecting) {
    selectionEndX = event.clientX;
    selectionEndY = event.clientY;

    let width = Math.abs(selectionEndX - selectionStartX);
    let height = Math.abs(selectionEndY - selectionStartY);

    selectionRectangle.style.width = width + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.height = height + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.left = Math.min(selectionEndX, selectionStartX) + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.top = Math.min(selectionEndY, selectionStartY) + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.display = 'block';

    widgets.forEach((widget) => {
      const widgetRect = widget.getBoundingClientRect();
      const isIntersecting = isRectangleIntersecting(widgetRect, {
        x: Math.min(selectionStartX, selectionEndX),
        y: Math.min(selectionStartY, selectionEndY),
        width,
        height,
      });
      if (isIntersecting) {
        widget.classList.add('selected');
      } else {
        widget.classList.remove('selected');
      }
    });
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  if (isSelecting) {
    isSelecting = false;
    selectionRectangle.remove();
  }
});

function isRectangleIntersecting(rect1, rect2) {
  return (
    rect1.left >= rect2.x &&
    rect1.top >= rect2.y &&
    rect1.right <= rect2.x + rect2.width &&
    rect1.bottom <= rect2.y + rect2.height
  );
}
```

```css
#selection-rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999999;
}

.widgets.selected {
  outline-color: blue;
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: dashed;
}

.widgets {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid #212128;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 166px;
  min-height: 66px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  image-resolution: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.widget-header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #040c14;
  outline-color: white;
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="widget1" class="widgets" style="left: 50px; top: 50px;">
  <div id="widget1header" class="widget-header"></div>
</div>
<div id="widget2" class="widgets" style="left: 150px; top: 150px;">
  <div id="widget2header" class="widget-header"></div>
</div>
<div id="widget3" class="widgets" style="left: 250px; top: 250px;">
  <div id="widget3header" class="widget-header"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line and remove dragElement function

```
 widgets.forEach(function (element) {         
     element.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
         event.target.closest('.widgets').classList.add('selected');
     });
 });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).